# Troubles understanding templates, template mixins, template functions and scope in D

Tags: templates, scope, d

In D a template instantiation is evaluated within the scope where the mixin appears, not where the template declaration is defined. Template mixins instead can be used when to evaluate the body within the scope where the mixin appears.
But what can I do when I have a template functions and I want its body to be evaluated in the calling scope ? I can't find a way to translate it in something equivalent.

Let's take the following example with two modules, `module1` and `module2`:

```
module module1;
import std.stdio;
public void test(string field)(string msg)
{
    mixin("static if (__traits(isArithmetic, " ~ field ~ " )) \n"
          ~ "  writeln(msg);\n");
}
```

and

```
module module2;
import module1;
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    float y;
};

void main()
{
    module1.test!("Foo.x")("ok");
}
```

Try to compile this with fail with the error `undefined identifier Foo.x`, because Foo is not visible inside module1. Is there a way to rewrite this in a way that the template argument is evaluated in module2 instead of module1.
If this is not possible, is there a way to get an object representing "Foo.x" and pass it as the template argument ? (This wouldn't solve the generic case, but at least would be useful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either pass the type at the call site, or use an alias argument to the template. Template alias parameters are the more general way to do it though. With this, you pass a symbol - not the name, but the whole thing, so it doesn't need to do a scope lookup in the template - and work with that. Again, no need to mix in here:

```
module module1;
import std.stdio;
// alias field instead of string field...
// the static is needed too because otherwise dmd complains that Foo.x needs a this to be usable
static public void test(alias field)(string msg)
{
     // and then use it directly
    static if (__traits(isArithmetic, typeof(field) ))
          writeln(msg);
}
```

Even if you are mixing in generated string code, you would always use the local name, field, instead of the stringized name. mixin(field.stringof) would be a mistake, instead just mixin ("field").

And at the usage point:

```
module module2;
import module1;
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    float y;
}

void main()
{
   // passing it without quotes
    module1.test!(Foo.x)("ok");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I was looking for. I came to a similar solution, using a template argument for the class, and keeping the string for the field, but is much better.Thanks.